# How can I adequately protect my SqLite database from race conditions in prepare statement?

Tags: c++, boost, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that is protected by my own locking. On a producer thread I prepare a statement with bound values. On a consumer thread I run the statement.

Here is some psuedo code representing my implementation:

```
class Database
{
    sqlite3_stmt* prepare(const char* statementStr)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_ptr lock(myMutex);
        sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mySqlDatabase, statementStr, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        return stmt;
    }

    int step(sqlite3_stmt* stmt)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_ptr lock(myMutex);
        return sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }

    boost::mutex myMutex;
}

Database mDatabase;

class Producer
{
public:
    void produce(const char* statementStr){
        sqlite3_stmt* stmt = mDatabase.prepare(statementStr);
        // now push it onto the consumer's queue
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    void consume() {
        mDatabase.step(statementQueue.pop());
    }
}
```

I am seeing a race condition inside of my prepare statement. My question is, how can I adequately protect my code to prevent such a race condition?

**Update**
The fact that I access the database from multiple threads seems pertinent. I do the population of my data structures on one thread, while further processing (updates, inserts and deletes) come from a processing thread. The processing thread holds a queue of prepared statements.

Comment: Do you have a lock around `statementQueue`? If not you should have one considering `Producer` and `Consumer` both access it.

Comment: Yeah the statement queue is protected. The race condition I am seeing causes a seg fault at various points within sqlite3_prepare_v2

Comment: Is *every* `sqlite3_`* call protected with `myMutex`?

Comment: @CL - yes, I have protected all sqlite calls.